# make glossaries \glslink respect the first-use

Tags: hyperref, glossaries, acronyms

I would like to have a `\glslink`-style command, that respects the first use flag of an abbreviation i.e. printing the abbreviation in parantheses if this is the first occurance.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[acronym,toc]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries


\newacronym{abc}{ABC}{Arbitrary Bull Crap}
\begin{document}


I would need some more \glslink{abc}{Arbitrary Bull Crappings}.
This is some \gls{abc}.

\end{document}
```

Output should be:

`I would need some more Arbitrary Bull Crappings (ABC). This is some ABC.`

Output is:

`I would need some more Arbitrary Bull Crappings. This is some Arbitrary Bull Crap (ABC).`

Unfortunately I could not find a corresponding option in the documentation and fiddling with the inerts of package commands is not my strong suite.

Is there an easy solution for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found **a solution**, although not the best I guess.

After enough digging in the documentation I found the `\ifglsunused{}{}{}` command, that executes code depending on the first-use flag of the given gls-entry.

```
\newcommand{\GlsPara}[2]{%
    \ifglsused{#1}{%
        \glslink{#1}{#2}%
    }{%
        \glslink{#1}{#2 (\acrshort{#1})\xspace}%
        \glsunset{#1}%
    }%
}%

\newcommand{\GlsParaPl}[2]{%
    \ifglsused{#1}{%
        \glslink{#1}{#2}%
    }{%
        \glslink{#1}{#2 (\acrshortpl{#1})\xspace}%
        \glsunset{#1}%
    }%
}%
```

From that I derived these two commands, that add my short acronym depending on the first-use state and actually sets the first-use flag afterwards, so everything works as expected.

Unfortunately this does not respect your chosen acronym style at all, but instead uses my hardcoded choice of `"<long>(<short>)"` If someone wants to improve this to work with any custom style -- go ahead :D